# Subclass member variable as argument for main-class constructor in initialization list = crash?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization-list

Very new to programming so forgive me for maybe not seeing something obvious.

Basically I just want to know why all three codes do compile, but the resulting executables CRASH in cases TWO and THREE
(I marked the differences with comments)

### ONE - compiles

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string testrace = "dog"; //defining it only globally

class Attributes {
    public:
    Attributes (string race){
        if (race == "human"){
            intelligence = 10;}
        else if (race == "dog"){
            intelligence = 4;}
    }
    int intelligence;
};

class Dalmatian: public Attributes{
    public:
        // but NOT locally
        Dalmatian (): Attributes{testrace} { //using it as an argument
            cout << "do i even arrive here" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Dalmatian bob;
    cout << bob.intelligence << endl;
}
```

### TWO - crashes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Attributes {
    public:
    Attributes (string race){
        if (race == "human"){
            intelligence = 10;}
        else if (race == "dog"){
            intelligence = 4;}
    }
    int intelligence;
};

class Dalmatian: public Attributes{
    public:
        string testrace = "dog"; //only defining it locally
        Dalmatian (): Attributes{testrace} { //using it as argument
            cout << "do i even arrive here" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Dalmatian bob;
    cout << bob.intelligence << endl;
}
```

### THREE - crashes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string testrace = "dog"; //defining it globally

class Attributes {
    public:
    Attributes (string race){
        if (race == "human"){
            intelligence = 10;}
        else if (race == "dog"){
            intelligence = 4;}
    }
    int intelligence;
};

class Dalmatian: public Attributes{
    public:
        string testrace = "dog"; // AND locally
        Dalmatian (): Attributes{testrace} { //using it as argument
            cout << "do i even arrive here" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Dalmatian bob;
    cout << bob.intelligence << endl;
}
```

What I am looking for, of course, is a working alternative to example TWO.
However I am also interested in an explanation why all of the three pieces of code will compile fine, but executables resulting from 2 and 3 will crash.

EDIT: I do know that examples ONE and THREE don't make sense, I used them for demonstrational purposes. (Also fixed my wording, compiler did fine, executable crashed);

EDIT2: I do, of course, realize that I could just replace "testrace" with ""dog"", but for easier transferability to other subclasses, I would prefer a solution that lets me use a variable argument for Attributes(), that I can vary depending on the subclass, that is invoking the main class.

Comment: It's most likely *not* your *compiler* that is crashing, but rather the program that you compiled and then ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off when you have

```
...
string testrace = "dog";
Dalmatian (): Attributes{testrace}
...
```

`testrace` will hide the global `testrace` as class members supersede global variables when you are in class scope.  This means both example two and three use the same variable, the class member variable.

The reason two and three crash because you are trying to use a variable that has no been constructed before.  When you get to

```
Dalmatian (): Attributes{testrace}
```

`testrace` has not yet been constructed.  Even though you have `string testrace = "dog";` in the class body that initialization doesn't happen until after `Attributes{testrace}` is called.  So `Attributes (string race)` gets a uninitialized string and using it is undefined behavior and also causes your crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains a lot.
Can you suggest a workaround, that lets me define the "race" of a subclass like "Dalmatian" and then lets me hand the value of "race" over to the parent class "Attributes" as an argument inside the initialization list?

Comment: @TrveBlack Your not going to be able to pass state from the derived object to the base object as the derived object is not even constructed until after the base class is.  [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) might work for you though

Comment: you can define a static const member, and use it for both passing to base class and initialisation of your non-static member

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the time that `Attributes` is constructed the `testrace` variable is yet uninitialized, and accessing it gives you undefined behavior.

You can simply fix this by writing

```
    Dalmatian (): Attributes{"dog"} { //using it as argument
        cout << "do i even arrive here" << endl;
    }
```

See the working code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d1293e4136d2ea6).